# Camera connection and disconnection catch

Tags: c++, opencv

Hey guys,
I'm using OpenCV with the C++ API, and in order for my project to be more reliable I need a certain camera connection\disconnection handling.
I have searched for how-to's, but I could only find answers that require an ugly hack in order to do so.

Can you suggest a cleaner way to do it?

Thnx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting an unplugged capture device (OpenCV)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028463/detecting-an-unplugged-capture-device-opencv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Detecting camera connection/disconnection might require some tricks.

I suggest that you start another thread to check the success of `cvCreateCameraCapture()` in a loop, while your application is running.

Something like the following:

```
while (run_detection_thread) // global variable controlled by the main thread
{
  CvCapture* capture = cvCreateCameraCapture(-1); //-1 or whatever number works for you
  if (camera) //camera is connected
  {
    sleep(1);
  }
  else
  {
    // camera was disconnected        
  }
}
```

Comment: I have seen this solution already, but running another thread every few seconds seems time wasting. I develop a real-time system and this might cause unnecessary delays

Comment: Unfortunately there is no other way.

Comment: @Royi By the way, the idea is to have one additional thread running the entire time, and inside it there will be this loop for checking if the camera is still connected. It's not like you are creating a new thread for each check every second. Unless you are working with a CPU of 300MHz this is a very practical solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think that I have a good workaround for this problem. I create an auxiliary Mat array with zeros with the same resolution like the output from camera. I assign it to Mat array to which just after is assign the frame captured from camera and at the end I check the norm of this array. If it is equal zero it means that there was no new frame captured from camera.

```
VideoCapture cap(0);
if(!cap.isOpened()) return -1;

Mat frame;
cap >> frame;
Mat emptyFrame = Mat::zeros(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, CV_32F);

for(;;)
{
   frame = emptyFrame;
   cap >> frame;
   if (norm(frame) == 0) break;
}
```