# I want to put my application in waiting mode for camera connection

Tags: opencv, visual-c++, camera

My small program is for read camera feed and it is working fine. But when camera connection lost during running application at that time application is terminated.Actually application control can't come out from cvCaptureFromFile() function and after some time it gives me error. When camera connection lost during running application at that time I want to control of cvCaptureFromFile() function means I want to put my application in waiting mode for next frame from camera and when got camera connection back then my application should start read frame automatically from camera. I want to do like this. I tried a lot but can't get any solution.
I am using opencv 2.4.4 version.

**My cpp file is**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "cv.h"
#include "cxcore.h"
#include "highgui.h"
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include "stdio.h"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

char key;
IplImage* frame = cvCreateImage(cvSize(640,360),8,3);
int main()
{

    IplImage *frame1;
    back:
    CvCapture* input = cvCaptureFromFile("rtsp://admin:12345@10.101.16.112:554/ch1-s1?tcp");
    if(!input)
    {
        printf("\nWaiting for camera connection.");
        goto back;
    }
    while(1)
    {
        frame1 = cvQueryFrame(input);
        /*if(frame1 == NULL)
            printf("\nCamera is disconnected.");*/      

        cvResize(frame1,frame,1);
        cvShowImage("frame", frame);
        key = cvWaitKey(10);
        if (char(key) == 27)
           break;
    }
    cvReleaseCapture(&input);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check these related answers out to check for disconnected camera: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637425/camera-connection-and-disconnection-catch
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028463/detecting-an-unplugged-capture-device-opencv

Comment: first, please stop using opencv's no more maintained c-api. then, unfortunately, there's nothing you can do. once your app starts waiting for a frame, it will do so *forever*.

Comment: Except that there is something he can do; it is done in the other answer I pointed to.
Granted, it's not trivial to implement, but it appears to be possible.

Comment: Thank you Christopher Peterson, I am trying to develop it using thread.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it will help you out but try this once...

1) If you are connecting camera to one of the ports, then you can continuously poll that, is it active ? and if is not active then camera got disconnected and accordingly wait for it to become active.

Comment: I am using the IP camera and I think when camera is in disconnected mode then IP address will not be ping and IP address not ping so we can not check port.

Comment: You are saying that it's a IP based camera, so when Its IP will not ping that itself means that your camera got disconnected.you can put your application in waiting mode when your cameras IP is not pinging and as soon as you get reply from that IP, resume your appllication.

Comment: I did exactly like that but my application can't come out from cvQueryFrame() function.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue might not be with the cvCaptureFromFile() function but with the frame1 = cvQueryFrame(input) command. Can you uncomment out the if statements below this command and clarify if camera disconnected is been printed out.

Sorry but can't do this myself as i currently don't have access to the opencv library

Comment: Also, with regards to berak's comment this is incorrect as the function should return a NULL responce if the image cannot be read as specified in the docs- http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html

Comment: execution of code doesn't go down when camera is disconnected even if statement is uncommented. It will wait for sometime and after sometime it gives error.

Comment: It should provide some kind of feedback after attempting to grab a frame. Regardless the solution that Christopher Peterson provided seems plausible. Also depending on how long the wait is before it throw an error, you cal always try to put the frame1 = cvQueryFrame(input); command in a try and catch error so when it throw an error try to reconnect to the camera (i.e repeat this command CvCapture* input = cvCaptureFromFile("rtsp://admin:12345@10.101.16.112:554/ch1-s1?tcp");)

Comment: Thank you Eni, I am gonna check it.