# Webcam APIs for C++

Tags: c++, opencv, webcam

So I was using OpenCV to capture from my webcam, although I have hit a problem. Seems OpenCV has no way of detecting if the camera has been disconnected. So I was wondering if anyone knows any other webcam APIs for c++ that could be used as an alternative, or if anyone knows how to detect disconnected/reconnected webcams using OpenCV I could even continue using that.

Comment: which openCV version are you using???

Comment: because it can be a duplicated question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028463/detecting-an-unplugged-capture-device-opencv)

Comment: I did see this but it didn't work for me. Although it wasn't on a separate thread so  I can try it again.